# Картинки в ряд с автоматическим ресайзом изображения

Tags: html, css

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы изображения автоматически сузились и встали в ряд в 500px (`.models_covers {width: 500px;}`)?

width с 500px может поменяться например на 800px и соответственно всё должно само подогнаться и картинок в ряд уже будет не 3, а например 5.

Выглядеть должно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.models_covers {width: 500px;}
```

```html
<div class="models_covers">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если можно использовать flex, то вот так

```css
.models_covers {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="models_covers">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Если без флекса, то

```
.models_covers{
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.models_covers div{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое! :)

Comment: я кстати не уточнил, а как сделать, чтобы изображения еще переносились? Например не помещается в ряд всё и оно переносится? Сейчас просто всё в один ряд пытается уместиться.

Comment: Да, при таком подходе элементы всегда будут помещаться в родителе, сколько бы их не было. При добавлении новых элементов, размеры картинок будут уменьшаться с сохранением соотношения сторон, то есть помещаться они будут всегда.

Comment: получается нет нормального решения под это, кроме как самому размеры изображений прописывать?

Comment: Если задача стоит в том, чтобы картинки всегда были в один ряд, выглядели нормально, без искажения соотношения сторон, то можно использовать метод из поста. При таком подходе по идее не существует такого случая, когда картинки могут не уместится в один ряд на ширине родителя. Если же нужно, чтобы было определенное количество картинок в ряд, то это уже иная задача. Тогда нужно будет задать ширину обертке div, прописать flex-wrap:wrap для .models_covers .

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте использовать относительные значения ширины самих картинок.
Соответственно с изменением количества картинок значения ширины должны быть откорректированы.

```css
.models_covers {
    min-width: 300px;
}

.models_covers img{
    width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div class="models_covers">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/6d/a0/e16da0913ef1eea4cd5bd401081ad2b2--hairstyles-for-ladies-short-hairstyles-for-girls.jpg" />
</div>
```